# Проблема с использованием VexCL в расширении Python

Tags: c++, python, opencl

Недавно открыл для себя чудесную библиотеку VexCL, решил попробовать использовать её для ускорения работы расширения для языка Python, выполняющего ряд математических вычислений. В расширении выполняются поэлементные операции с массивами, которые я хотел бы заменить шаблонными выражениями с векторами VexCL. Однако, по какой-то причине, при загрузке модуля Python напрочь виснет. Проблема, скорее всего, не в коде модуля, т.к. зависает всё ещё до того, как программа доходит до первых строчек его кода. Контекст храню в глобальной переменной-структуре.

```
// file.h
#include "vexcl/devlist.hpp"

struct Config
{
    bool use_vexcl;
    vex::Context vexcl_ctx;
    Config();
};

extern Config config;

void init_config();

//file.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "config.h"

using namespace std;

Config::Config()
    : use_vexcl(true)
    , vexcl_ctx(vex::Filter::Any && vex::Filter::DoublePrecision)
{
    cout << "Config constructor with VexCL" << endl;
    if (!vexcl_ctx) throw std::runtime_error("No VexCL devices available");
}

Config config;

void init_config()
{
    cout << "Init config..." << endl;
    config = Config();
}
```

Функция `init_config()` выполняется в расширении сразу же после всех `#include`. Однако и до неё поток выполнения программы не доходит (не выводится "Init config..."). Если закомментировать весь код с использованием VexCL, выполнение не останавливается.

Связано ли это с VexCL, или с какими-то логическими ошибками в моём коде? Как можно это исправить (и можно ли вообще)?

P.S. Стоит отметить, что модуль расширения Python по сути является библиотекой dll. Использовался OpenCL бекенд к VexCL.

Проверялось на Windows 8.1, использовался Python 3.4 и компилятор из Microsoft Visual С++ 10.0. Проект организован таким образом, что изложенный выше код является частью библиотеки, линкуемой с расширением статически.

Comment: Ой.... Ну там масса вариантов может быть, если используется openCL, лично я встречался со странными ситуациями когда все стоит, но софт openCL устройства не видит напрочь. И это при работе с openCL напрямую. А у вас еще две прокладки, мест для проблем еще больше. Отладчиком смотреть надо...

Comment: Я использую VexCL для создания питоновских расширений (с помощью boost.python), при этом таких проблем не возникает. В вашем коде вы инициализируете контекст дважды: первый раз в конструкторе `Config()`, который вызывается при создании глобального объекта `config`, второй раз внутри функции `init_config()`. Т.е. зависание скорее всего происходит при первой инициализации. Работает ли тот же код VexCL на вашей машине вне питоновского модуля?

Comment: @ddemidov Изначально такой двойной инициализации у меня не было, однако где-то я прочитал, что глобальные переменные в dll файлах не инициализируются (думал, проблема в этом). В любом случае, без `init_config()` происходит то же самое. Врапперы для c++ классов описываю на Cython. Вне пиотоновского модуля всё нормально (пробовал на двух машинах).

Comment: В таком случае идей больше нет. Опыта работы с cython у меня нет, но попробуйте посмотреть этот проект: https://github.com/gregvw/chebyshev-gpu, там связка vexcl-cython работала.

Comment: @ddemidov Спасибо за помощь! В данном проекте контекст инициализируется как поле класса, объект которого создаётся в ходе выполнения конструктора Cython-враппера для этого класса и хранится в связанной с ней структурой, т.е. хранится и инициализируется в локальной области видимости. У меня же он создаётся при инициализации глобальной переменной, то есть по логике как бы при загрузке модуля, но на этом месте программа виснет. Если перенести инициализацию в локальную область видимости, например объявить `config` в `init_config()`, то всё работает как должно. Не могу понять, почему так...

Comment: Попробуйте еще хранить в `config` не экземпляр класса `Config`, а умный указатель на него (`std::unique_ptr<Config> config`). Тогда инициализация будет гарантированно выполняться внутри `init_config()`.

Comment: @ddemidov Спасибо за совет! Вы не знаете, может ли это быть связано с тем, что изложенный код у меня собирается в библиотеку `.lib` и линкуется с модулем расширения статически?

Comment: Не знаю. Возможно, проблема в том, что порядок инициализации глобальных объектов в C++ не определен, и инициализация контекста vexcl происходит до полной инициализации окружения cython.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы избежать зависания нужно убрать инициализацию контекста из глобальной области видимости. Например можно объявить и инициализировать `config` в `init_config()` и вернуть его в вызывающий код, или объявить поле `vexcl_ctx` как `vex::Context*` и создать объект в динамической памяти в функции `init_config()`.

Как только инициализация контекста происходит в глобальной области видимости, наблюдается зависание интерпретатора при загрузке модуля расширения. Прочие же глобальные объекты инициализируются и работают как положено. Причину такого поведения я не понял, буду признателен, если кто-то объяснит.